# TF model is accepting any image input size after the first inference, but only 224x224 should be allowed

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm facing a very strange error which I cannot get my head around.

When I run this code below, it works fine as the model is expecting a 224x224 input image. However, if I change the image to say 224x225, it will give an error sayng that it was expecting a 224x224. This is as expected.

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

#load model from model.h5
model = tf.keras.models.load_model('model.h5')

# Load model weights from weights.h5
model.load_weights('weights.h5')

image_path = 'image1.jpg'
img = image.load_img(image_path, target_size=(224, 224))
img_array = image.img_to_array(img)
img_array = np.expand_dims(img_array, axis=0)
print(img_array.shape)
predictions = model.predict(img_array)
if predictions[0][0] > 0.5:
    print("class 1")
else:
    print("class 2")
```

Now, let's say I ran the code above with a 224x224 input image, so it doesn't give an error. However, if I now subsequently run inference on another image with dimensions, say 224x225, it doesn't give an error! How come that's possible? **It seems as if the model only cares about the first inference being 224x224, and any following inferences can be of any dimension.**

```
image_path = 'image2.jpg'
img = image.load_img(image_path, target_size=(224, 225)) #THIS SHOULD GIVE ERROR BUT IT DOESNT
img_array = image.img_to_array(img)
img_array = np.expand_dims(img_array, axis=0)
print(img_array.shape)
predictions = model.predict(img_array)
if predictions[0][0] > 0.5:
    print("class 1")
else:
    print("class 2")
```

Comment: traceback required. [mre] required. `image` is undefined.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz sorry, that was a formatting error with the ```, so that import line was hidden. I updated it

Comment: Would you provide the summary of the used model (layers shapes and structure)